# How to give authentication to load pages?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, authentication

I have created some pages using html and php. In home page I have links of all pages. Now I want to add authentication to each page. The page should not get open without the authentication.

For this I have created one login page which will check authentication.
Now from home page I want to open the login page if any page's link is clicked, and if the login is successful I want to open the page which link is clicked.

Home Page:

```
    <!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Questions</title>
</head>
<body>

<a href="chapter.php">Add a chapter</a><br><br>
<a href="MainPage.php">Upload a file</a><br><br>
<a href="videoFile.php">Upload a video</a><br><br>
<a href="mcq.php">Add a question</a><br><br>
<a href="chapterDelete.php">Delete chapters</a><br><br>
<a href="deleteFiles.php">Delete Files</a><br><br>
<a href="deleteVideoFiles.php">Delete video Files</a><br><br>
<a href="deleteQuestions.php">Delete questions</a>

</body>
</html>
```

Login page:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<body>

<form action="Login.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    Enter Username : <input name = "userName" type = "text"><br><br>
    Enter Password : <input name = "pass" type = "text"><br><br>

    <input name="submit" type="submit" value = "Submit"><br><br>

<?php

header("Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate"); // HTTP 1.1.
header("Pragma: no-cache"); // HTTP 1.0.
header("Expires: 0"); // Proxies.

ini_set('display_errors', 1);
error_reporting(1);
ini_set('error_reporting', E_ALL);

$dbh = new PDO('mysql:host=174.138.74;dbname=_pro','rpro', 'ro12345');

if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {

    if (!empty($_POST['userName']) && !empty($_POST['pass'])) {

        $stmt = $dbh->prepare("select * FROM `users` WHERE `username`= :uName and `pass` = :pass");
        $stmt->bindParam("uName", $_POST['userName']);
        $stmt->bindParam("pass", $_POST['pass']);
        $stmt->execute();
        $result = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

        $count = $stmt->rowCount();

        if ($count > 0) {
            echo 'Login Successful.';

            ?>

    <?php
        } else {

            echo 'Please enter correct username and password.';

        }
    }
    else{
        echo 'Please enter username and password.';
    }
}

?>


</form>
</body>
</head>

</html>
```

How can I achieve this? Please help. Thank you..

Comment: You can create a login-form and use some kind of userid as session variable. When opening one of the protected pages, PHP will check if the user is logged in and validated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make your all links like these...

```
<a href="login.php?redirect=chapter">Add a chapter</a><br><br>
<a href="login.php?redirect=MainPage">Upload a file</a><br><br>
<a href="login.php?redirect=videoFile">Upload a video</a><br><br>
<a href="login.php?redirect=mcq">Add a question</a><br><br>
<a href="login.php?redirect=chapterDelete">Delete chapters</a><br><br>
<a href="login.php?redirect=deleteFiles">Delete Files</a><br><br>
<a href="login.php?redirect=deleteVideoFiles">Delete video Files</a><br><br>
<a href="login.php?redirect=deleteQuestions">Delete questions</a>
```

Then when user will click on any link, it'll redirect them to `login.php` page. At there make all kind of validation of user credentials & if validation is found out as TRUE then get `redirect` part of URL from the previous link & reconstruct the destination page once again by

```
$destination_page = $_GET['redirect'];
```

& redirect the user to that page else ask the user for login again.

Comment: sorry I did not get this -then get redirect part of URL from the previous link & reconstruct the destination page once again.

Comment: how can I redirect user to $destination_page?

Comment: What I wanted to say, suppose user click on the following link ```<a href="login.php?redirect=chapter">Add a chapter</a><br><br>```. Then destination page will be like ```chapter.php```. When your user validation will over & if found as TRUE you can redirect user to the destination page which is at here is ```chapter.php``` else ask for relogin to teh system.

Comment: For redirect user in PHP you can use code like this - ```header("Location: yourfile.php"); exit();```

Comment: if ($count > 0) {
            echo 'Login Successful.';
           // $_SESSION['authenticated_user'] = $_POST['userName'];

            $destination_page = $_GET['redirect'];
            header("Location: $destination_page");
            exit();

        } else {

            echo 'Please enter correct username and password.';

        }

Comment: I tried to add this in login page on logn successfull, but it did not redirect me to the page.

Comment: ```$destination_page = $_GET['redirect'].'.php'``` use this.

Comment: no it worked but getting this error, Notice: Undefined index: redirect in /var/www/html/powerpro/Login.php on line 40 , its taking its local path

Comment: Did you get my point what I want to say. Just don't blindly copy & paste.

Comment: if u r getting notice error(undefined index) on your ```login.php``` file it means... in your login.php file $GET has no index by ```redirect```.  Check that it should be at there.

Comment: if this link ```<a href="login.php?redirect=chapter">Add a chapter</a>``` is in ```home.php``` & user click on that link it'll take him to ```login.php```. In this case in ```login.php``` $GET variable should have the index ```redirect``` in it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/142897/discussion-between-sid-and-mi6crazyheart).

Comment: if the page is accessed directly then how can I redirect it to the same page trough login page?

Answer (score 0):

You can authenticate using sessions as:

- After successfully logged in, create $_SESSION[]
- Create common file where you can check is session set
- if session is not set then you can redirect to login page
- include this file in all pages

Answer (score 0):

Set a session variable. Note that you should put headers at the top, before any output.

```
header("Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate"); // HTTP 1.1.
header("Pragma: no-cache"); // HTTP 1.0.
header("Expires: 0"); // Proxies.

ini_set('display_errors', 1);
error_reporting(1);
ini_set('error_reporting', E_ALL);

$dbh = new PDO('mysql:host=174.138.74;dbname=_pro','rpro', 'ro12345');

if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {

    if (!empty($_POST['userName']) && !empty($_POST['pass'])) {

        $stmt = $dbh->prepare("select * FROM `users` WHERE `username`= :uName and `pass` = :pass");
        $stmt->bindParam("uName", $_POST['userName']);
        $stmt->bindParam("pass", $_POST['pass']);
        $stmt->execute();
        $result = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

        $count = $stmt->rowCount();

        if ($count > 0) {

            $_SESSION['authenticated_user'] = $_POST['userName'];
            header("Location: http://www.example.com/loginsuccess.php");
            ?>

    <?php
        } else {

            echo 'Please enter correct username and password.';

        }
    }
    else{
        echo 'Please enter username and password.';
    }
}else{
?><!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<body>

<form action="Login.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    Enter Username : <input name = "userName" type = "text"><br><br>
    Enter Password : <input name = "pass" type = "text"><br><br>

    <input name="submit" type="submit" value = "Submit"><br><br>

</form>
</body>
</head>

</html>
<?php
}

?>
```

Now on the other pages check if they are authenticated by checking the session.

```
<?php 
if (!isset($_SESSION['authenticated_user'])){
    header("Location: http://www.example.com/noaccess.php");
} 
?>
```

Comment: if login is successful I want to show the page, now it remained on login page though login was successful.@Antony Thompson

Comment: I changed it. You need to put the form at the end of the page. Then from if the login is successful you can add a redirect header to the loginsuccess page.

Comment: how can I get page's link by this? it redirected me to example page.

Comment: Yes you need to change the example.com redirect to the file you have your links in

Comment: but how can I make sure which link is clicked?